# Date subtraction from columns in database

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.1

[This is my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek2jw.png)

It has two columns `durasi` and `mulai` and I want the total column reflect `durasi - mulai`

Can someone tell me how to do this? I am using Laravel 5.1

this is my controller :

```
public function getTambah()
    {
        return view('tambah_user');
    }
    public function postSimpanTambah()
    {
        $simpan= array();
        $simpan['nama']=Request::input('nama');
        $simpan['tanggal']=Request::input('tanggal');
        $simpan['deskripsi']=Request::input('deskripsi');
        $simpan['mulai']=Request::input('mulai');
        $simpan['durasi']=Request::input('durasi');

        DB::table('lembur_karyawan')->insert($simpan);
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
                    alert('Berhasil menambahkan data');
                    document.location='../user';
               </script>";
    }
```

and this is my view :

```
<h3>Tambah User</h3>
                <hr>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo url('user/simpan-tambah') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="Tambahkan Id">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Nama:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama" value="<?php echo  Auth::user()->name. '';?>" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Tanggal:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal" placeholder="Tambahkan Tanggal">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Deskripsi:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deskripsi" placeholder="Tambahkan Deskripsi">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Mulai:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="mulai" value="17:00" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Durasi:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="durasi" placeholder="Tambahkan Durasi">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse">Reset</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick='location.href="<?php echo url('admin') ?>"' class="btn btn-inverse">Batal</button>
                    </div>
            </div>  

            </form>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to calculate this when you insert the values in to your database? Can you show us the code you are using to insert the data?

Comment: Have you attempted anything you can show us?

Comment: already edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your `postSimpanTambah()` function slightly:

```
public function postSimpanTambah()
    {
        $simpan= array();
        $simpan['nama'] = Request::input('nama');
        $simpan['tanggal'] = Request::input('tanggal');
        $simpan['deskripsi'] = Request::input('deskripsi');
        $simpan['mulai'] = Request::input('mulai');
        $simpan['durasi'] = Request::input('durasi');
        $simpan['total'] = Request::input('durasi') - Request::input('mulai');

        DB::table('lembur_karyawan')->insert($simpan);
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
                    alert('Berhasil menambahkan data');
                    document.location='../user';
               </script>";
    }
```

Here we are simply adding in another value to your array called `total` and setting its value to `durasi - mulai`.

**Edit**

Given they are times, we can use Carbon to generate the difference:

```
$simpan['total'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('durasi')) - \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('mulai'));
```

Comment: oke thanks its anwers my question but is only subtract the hours how about the minute ?

Comment: what are the values that come from the `durasi` and `mulai` input?

Comment: yes. but the result only the hours not with the minute.

Comment: I understand that, but what values do `durasi` and `mulai` return from your form?

Comment: yes, i am input durasi and mulai from my form. should the result same with type durasi and mulai? example 18:30 - 17:20 then sould result is 1:10 ? but the result now is only 1. what should i do?

Comment: @AdamProjo Ahh I see - so they are times. See my edit above. I haven't tested it, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: i get respond, Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int. and i have already install carbon in my laravel, what should i do? have idea?